# WPF: Master - detail view with two datagrids and in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, master-detail

I'm trying to write a master - detail control that consists of a master datagrid and the detail datagrid. My scenario was following - I used the SelectedItem and bound it to a property in ModelView. The problem is - the SelectedItem in ViewModel is never used, so I can't get the information which item is selected in a master datagrid and cannot fetch the data for thos selection.

The code is below:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemHandler, Mode=TwoWay}"></toolkit:DataGrid>
```

And in ViewModel

```
private CustomerObjects _selectedItem;    
public CustomerObjects SelectedItemHandler {
                get { return _selectedItem; }
                set
                {
                         OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

                }

            }
```

The code in SelectedItemHandler is never used.
What could be the problem? Should I use another approach to create master - detail in MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `EventToCommand` behavior provided by the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) which will allow you to work with for instance the `LostFocus` (or any other for that matter) event of the Master control. Other approaches might include using a `DataGrid` for the Master and `TextBox` or `TextBlock` controls for the Detail.